# Trying to create a method to check if array contains only a 1 or 4

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
static boolean checkNum(int[] array) {

    boolean bool = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i] != 1 || array[i] != 4) {
            return !bool;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

I have tried coding this a few ways but have not had any luck. How should I be doing it? it just needs to go through the array and find anything that isn't a 1 or 4, otherwise it should be true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

- `array[i] != 1 || array[i] !=4` will *always* evaluate to `true`. Any number is either not 1 or not 4.

  You are looking for the condition `array[i] != 1 && array[i] !=4`, which says "the number is not 1 *and* not 4". Another valid alternative would be `!(array[i] == 1 || array[i] == 4)`, which says "the number is not *either* 1 *or* 4". Which one you end up going with is up to your personal preference.
- As others pointed out, the `i++` inside the loop is redundant and makes the loop skip every second element.

---

This version should fix your problems:

```
static boolean checkNum(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i] != 1 && array[i] != 4) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

You see how it was additionally possible to get rid of the variable `bool`?

**Bonus:** It is even more clear if you use a [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop instead of the for loop:

```
static boolean checkNum(int[] array) {

    for (int i : array) {

        if (i != 1 && i != 4) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great! Mind accepting my answer as correct then? :-)

Comment: Not critical, but I find `!(i == 1 || i == 4)` a bit easier to read/understand.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I added it to the post for completeness' sake!

Answer (score 4):

Logically, if the value at the current position is not 1 **and** is not 4 then return false.

```
static boolean checkNum(int[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] != 1 && array[i] != 4){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would also recommend the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
static boolean checkNum(int[] array){
    for(int val : array){
        if (val != 1 && val != 4){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's time to move to a [more modern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) (which I think is the same)?

Comment: @user1803551 The link is still good. And it indicates the age of the feature. In this case, the `for-each` loop was added in Java 5.

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking every second element because you are incrementing `i` twice.

Remove this line: `i++;`

You are already incrementing `i` in the for loop here: `for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){`

Comment: it still only prints only false :S so that wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

if(array[i] != 1 && array[i] !=4){
or
 if(!(array[i] = 1 || array[i] =4)){

You've managed to conflate both of the correct tests that would work and produce one that doesn't work.  Pretty easy to do, so always check your complex boolean expressions.

Good luck :)